# Event Emitter is not working with Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am using the Login Wrapper Component with child component named

```
 <app-login>
```

. The click event from child component doesn't invoke parent method.  
**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-login',
  template: `
  <app-login [user]="user" (actionEvent)="loginUser($event)" ">

  </app-login>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./employee-login.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  constructor() {
    this.user =  new User();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(someData) {
    console.log({dat: someData});
  }

}
```

**Login Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  template: `
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="email"  name="email"  [(ngModel)]="user.email"  (ngModelChange)="change()"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email"  required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" (ngModelChange)="change()"   class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  required>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <button type="button" (click)="loginAction()"  class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user: User = new User();
  @Output() userChanged = new EventEmitter();


  @Output() actionEvent: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  loginAction(){
    console.log({user: this.user});
    this.actionEvent.emit(this.user);
  }

  change(){
    this.userChanged.emit(this.user);
  }

}
```

The same code is working on other template but somehow its not working here, the console output from child component is working but on parent component is its not.

My Package.json file looks like following:
**Package.json**

```
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.5.1",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.11",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
```

Comment: Is there some error output on click?

Comment: looks ok to me. Do you see any errors on console?

Comment: There is an extra `"` in your <app-login>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<app-login [user]="user" (actionEvent)="loginUser($event)" ">

  </app-login>
```

See the Additional `"`.

```
<app-login [user]="user" (actionEvent)="loginUser($event)">

  </app-login>
```